# LocalFileSystem on Chrome Apps losing date after App updates

Tags: google-chrome, storage, offline, updating

Im making a chrome App that retrieves a lot of images/videos and using LocalFileSystem to store the files on the local sandbox, everything is fine but If I update the App using their automated update via the file.xml and the manifest url, the new crx is installed and the files stored in the LocalFileSystem is wiped out, so the app will need to download them once again.

I can see the  the chrome.storage.local is persistent but using the LocalFileSystem between updates is not, anyway to change this or any solution to save the files/videos and make them be persistent between updates?

Im using:
window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(webkitStorageInfo.PERSISTENT, quotaFileSize, function (grantedBytes) {
        window.requestFileSystem(webkitStorageInfo.PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, function (fs) {

To save the files, which it does perfectly and retrieving the files work fine, the problem is that when the app updates it erases everything on the file system.

Anyway to persist this files stored in the filesystem when the app/extension is updated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you encountered same issue, it's a bug of Chrome: 
"[Storage/ext gets nuked (including persistent filesystem storage) at Chrome OS auto-updates](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=328637)"